# Свойство для для определённых элементов

Tags: css

Представьте ситуацию, что у Вас есть какое-то количество блоков, которые расположены в виде сетки, по три блока в ширину.

```css
.grid {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Задача в том, чтобы сделать отступы блоков друг от друга так, чтобы у крайних, ближе к границам родителя, их не было.

```css
.grid {
  display: block;
  width: 310px;
  height: 315px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* Нижний отступ проще, он у всех есть.. */
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item.bbb { /* Для примера. Такой вариант не устраивает.. */
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item bbb"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item bbb"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item bbb"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Есть ли какой-то способ реализации этого, допустим через `:nth-child`..

---

Сразу оговорюсь, решение нужно на чистом CSS, без JS\JQ, Flex'ов и Grid'ов, и т.п.
Если такое не возможно, щито поделать, буду велосипедить на JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать комбинацию - `padding-top/left` для родителя и `margin-bottpm/right` для потомков. Во-первых, не создаёт дополнительного правила, во-вторых - количество блоков может произвольно меняться, без правки стилей.

```css
.grid {
  display: block;
  width: 315px;
  height: 315px;
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px; /* padding-top-left */
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0; /* margin-right-bottom */
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Но и тут не без минусов - становиться затруднительно оперировать родительским внутренним отступом (хотя, это можно нивелировать использованием `margin`, `border` и `box-shadow`).

Comment: Ох, этот вариант будет даже лучше, ибо он подойдёт для любого кол-ва блоков по горизонтали. Так что изменю своё решение. Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так

```
.grid {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

либо

```
.grid .item {
      margin-right:5px;
}
.grid .item:nth-child(3n) {
     margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: `..решение нужно на чистом CSS..`

Comment: это чистый css. просто добавьте это к тем стилям, что у вас есть и все.

Comment: А, ну да, не считаю чистым, но да ладно. Тем не менее флексы и гриды отпадают.

Comment: отредактировал ответ. предлагаю первому и второму .item в строке делать отступ справа, а каждому третьему .item убирать его.

Comment: Вот за второй вариант приму ответ)